# how to create new text widget for flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to create a custom text-widget in the Flutter. I have to change any color it accepts in the style with an opacity of 0.7. If it does not have a style, I have to show the color from the default style with an opacity of 0.7 .

My problem is creating a new text widget with the feature I described.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by default style? -> "I have to show the color from the default style with an opacity of 0.7". Do you have default styles already defined, or default themes from Material App?

Comment: Okey , What is meant by default style? When you use a text widget and do not give it a text style, it follows a text style by default. According to the Flutter document, it uses DefaultTextStyle in this case.
Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could have used the widget `Opacity` very easily, but due to the `Flutter document` for `Opacity` Widget ([resource](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html)) and the high cost of `re-rendering` the child, it was not necessary.
The whole problem could be solved by `DefaultTextStyle`. You only need to pay attention to `handling the context`, which is `documented` in the code below.

Two modes are seen in the following code:

1- If `TextStyle` is `not defined` for your Text widget, it follows the default color at `DefaultTextStyle.of.(context)` or `Theme` and then manual Opacity value is also set.

2- If `TextStyle` is `defined` for your Text widget, it follows the defined color and its manual Opacity value is also set.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const double OPACITY_VALUE = 0.7;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// ATTENTION: parent of this context is Material App  .
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Builder(builder: (context2) {
          /// context2 is important because referred to parent , and parent is Scaffold .
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              /// color and textStyle of this text widget referred to current Theme or DefaultTextStyle .
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context2).style.copyWith(
                    color: DefaultTextStyle.of(context2)
                        .style
                        .color!
                        .withOpacity(OPACITY_VALUE)),
              ),
              const CustomizedTextWidget(color: Colors.purple),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomizedTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomizedTextWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      '0',
      style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 32)
          .copyWith(color: color.withOpacity(OPACITY_VALUE)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem:

You can make a function based Widget or a class based Widget:

Function based Widget:

```
Widget myCustomText({required String data, Color? customColor}) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 0.7,
      child: Text(
        data,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: customColor ?? Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Another approach is making a class based widget:

```
class MyCustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final Color? customColor;
  const MyCustomText({Key? key, required this.data, this.customColor})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 0.7,
      child: Text(
        data,
        style: TextStyle(color: customColor ?? Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how you can implement your custom text wherever required:
// Code M:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [

          //Widget based Implementation
          myCustomTextWidget(data: "Hello world"),
          myCustomTextWidget(data: "Hello Peter", customColor: Colors.amber),

          //Class based implementation
          MyCustomTextClassWidget(data: "Hello Spidey"),
          MyCustomTextClassWidget(data: "Hello 007", customColor: Colors.orange,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Explanation: Null(??) operator checks if whether the value is given or not and if not given, then it will used default value after it.

Conclusion: Using Class based Widget i.e. Approach Number 2 is more robust and using class based widget is recommended by Flutter Official Team. It is also rebuild freindly and highly performant.

Output of the above code(M):
[image: Output of Code M]

Comment: It is always advisable to apply opacity to the color itself instead of using the opacity widget since the latter is a lot slower.

Comment: using extension is an overkill, `TextStyle.copyWith` is enough

Comment: using opacity widget is expensive and not recommanded . refer to flutter doc about Opacity - widget : A widget that makes its child partially transparent. This class paints its child into an intermediate buffer and then blends the child back into the scene .
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html

Answer (score 0):

The working solution simply uses

- `ThemeData.primaryColor` for the configuration of default text color;
- If it does not have a `TextStyle` passes to `CustomTextWidget`, the default text color is used with an opacity of 0.7;
- If it does have a `TextStyle` passes to `CustomTextWidget`, the textStyle is used with an opacity of 0.7.

Codes here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: const HomeWidget(title: _title),
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        // default text color
        primaryColor: Colors.pink,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          // change the appbar color
          primary: Colors.green[800],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({
    Key? key,
    required String title,
  })  : _title = title,
        super(key: key);

  final String _title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          CustomTextWidget(text: 'text does not have a style'),
          CustomTextWidget(
            text: 'text with passed black color style and fontSize 24',
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              color: Colors.black
            ),
          ),
          CustomTextWidget(
            text: 'text with passed blue color style',
            textStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;

  const CustomTextWidget({Key? key, required this.text, this.textStyle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle finalTextStyle = textStyle ?? const TextStyle();
    final Color? finalColor = textStyle != null && textStyle!.color != null
        ? textStyle!.color
        : Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

    return Text(
      text,
      // it accepts in the style with an opacity of 0.7.
      style: finalTextStyle.copyWith(color: finalColor!.withOpacity(0.7)),
    );
  }
}
```

Expected outcome:

[image]